# ToggleClass doesn't work properly with FontAwesome

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I'm trying to change the triangle direction on click and with this code, everything works perfect, but now I want to change the first direction because the list is hidden, so, why when I change the first fa-caret-down with right and change the other triangle accordingly it doesn't work?

```
collapsible.append('<h5>' + scheme.name + " " + '<em class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></h5>');

if ($('.SchemeSearchExp').length) {
    $("div.schemeHead>h5").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.streetname').toggle();
        $(this).children("em").toggleClass('fa-caret-right');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on), when manipulation selector (i.e. removing and adding classes).

*Change your code to*

```
$(document).on('click', ".fa-caret-right", function(){
    $(this).next('.streetname').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-caret-down');
});
```

```
$(document).on('click', "em.fa", function () {
    $(this).next('.streetname').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container. A good read [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Additionally, You should use `if` block in the event handlers

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work for me, but if I modify my code with: `fa fa-caret-down fa-caret-right` and `.toggleClass("fa-caret-right")` it works as expected.
Is pretty weird that just with changing the direction of the triangle the same code doesn't work. you think is something related to Font-awesome? some kind of bug?

Comment: @Sebastiano, Issue has nothing to do with  Font-awesome

Comment: well.. my code works but if I change the direction doesn't work.  Same code just different direction of the triangle.

Comment: Try this once `$(document).on('click', "em.fa", function(){
    $(this).next('.streetname').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
});`

Comment: now it works, but I removed the `em.fa` from click and changed `$(document)` to attach the event at the div